# How to check if an array of dictionaries contans dictionaries in a scond array?

Tags: iphone, nsarray, nsdictionary

Hi I have two NSArrays containing NSDictionaries.
I how can I check if a dictionary in array a is also in array b?
I have an id key in the dictionaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the NSArray method containsObject: in a loop to check this Doc says:

> containsObject: Returns a Boolean value that indicates whether a given
>   object is present in the array.
>
> - (BOOL)containsObject:(id)anObject
>
> Parameters anObject An object.
>   Return Value YES if anObject is present in the array, otherwise NO.